# LINQ Distinct not using the IEqualityComparer?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have the following model:

```
public class Word {
      public string Original { get; set; }
      public string Normalized { get; set; }
      public string Root { get; set; }
      public string Subroot { get; set; }
      public Regex SubrootRegex { get; set; }
}
```

I have created the following three `IEqualityComparer<Word>`:

```
public class NormalizedWordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Word> {
     public bool Equals(Word x, Word y) {
          return x.Normalized == y.Normalized;
     }
     public int GetHashCode(Word obj) {
          return obj.GetHashCode();
     }
}

public class RootWordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Word> {
     public bool Equals(Word x, Word y) {
          return x.Root == y.Root;
     }
     public int GetHashCode(Word obj) {
          return obj.GetHashCode();
     }
}

public class SubrootWordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Word> {
     public bool Equals(Word x, Word y) {
          return x.Subroot == y.Subroot;
     }
     public int GetHashCode(Word obj) {
          return obj.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

In another class, I am trying to do the following:

```
_normalizedWords = ConfigurationFacade.Words.Select(w => {
     Word word = new Word() { Original = w };
     word.Normalized = Normalize(word, _filters);
     word.Root = GetRoot(word.Normalized, ConfigurationFacade.WordRootPercentage);
     word.Subroot = GetRoot(word.Root, ConfigurationFacade.WordSubrootPercentage);
     word.SubrootRegex = null; //Complicated regex here
     return word;
}).Distinct(new NormalizedWordComparer());

_wordRoots = _normalizedWords.Distinct(new RootWordComparer());
_wordSubroots = _wordRoots.Distinct(new SubrootWordComparer());
```

However, `_normalizedWords`, `_wordRoots` and `_wordSubroots` all end up with the same amount of elements, as if the `Distinct()` method didn't work or the comparer is being ignored.

I checked the elements with the debugger, and there are a lot that have the same `Root` value, so there should only be one of them in `_wordRoots`, but that's not the case, they are not removed or filtered.

Why is my `Distinct()` not working?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Little typo there. My bad!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is my Distinct() not working?

Because `Distinct` *first* checks the hash code (since it's a quick check to see if two object *could* be equal) and *then* calls `Equals`.  Since your `GetHashCode` implementations are all the same (and do not correspond to your `Equals` methods), `Distinct` is not working as you would expect.

Change your `GetHashCode` methods to correspond with `Equals`:

```
public class NormalizedWordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Word> {
     public bool Equals(Word x, Word y) {
          return x.Normalized == y.Normalized;
     }
     public int GetHashCode(Word obj) {
          return obj.Normalized.GetHashCode();
     }
}

public class RootWordComparer: IEqualityComparer<Word> {
     public bool Equals(Word x, Word y) {
          return x.Root == y.Root;
     }
     public int GetHashCode(Word obj) {
          return obj.Root.GetHashCode();
     }
}

public class SubrootWordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Word> {
     public bool Equals(Word x, Word y) {
          return x.Subroot == y.Subroot;
     }
     public int GetHashCode(Word obj) {
          return obj.Subroot.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

Comment: I see! It all makes sense now that you clarified it for me! Thank you!